# How to print every number that is divisible by either 3 or 5, but not both?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a function threeOrFive(max). It should loop every number that is divisible by either 3 or 5 but not both. So it won't loop 15 since it's divisible by both numbers but will print out "3, 5, 6 , 9, 10, 12, 18".

The code I've tried is

```
function threeOrFive(max){
    for(let i = 0; i<max; i+=3, i+=5){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

and

```
function threeOrFive(max){
    for(let i = 0; i<max; i+=3){
        if(i+=3 % max === 0 && i+=5 % max === 0){
            return false;
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `i += 3`?

Comment: To tell if a number is divisible by 3, use `i % 3 == 0`. And similarly for 5.

Comment: `return false` exits the whole function. So your loop will stop without going through all the numbers.

Comment: `i += 3, i += 5` is equivalent to `i += 8`

Comment: Your code makes very little sense. It looks like you just threw together code that randomly uses `3` and `5`, without really thinking through what you're doing, in the hopes that someone here would rewrite it for you.

Comment: Before being clever, be _correct_.  Consider starting with a version that just does `i++`.  Two useful checks would then be `(i%3==0)` (is divisible by 3) and `(i%5==0)` (is divisible by 5).  Then search the internet for [_fizzbuzz_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz), which is what this problem is classically named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function. This will return  a array of all numbers that divisible by 3 or 5 but not by both.

```
const threeOrFive = max => {
    const store = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < max; i++){
        if (i%3==0 && i%5==0) continue;
        else if (i%3==0) store.push(i);
        else if (i%5==0) store.push(i);
    }

    return store;
}
```